# MacOS HID - USB control transfer - HID API/libusb MacOS

Tags: macos, interface, usb, hid, iokit

I am trying to get reports from a **PS4** like controller for which I don't have access to firmware.

I've successfully managed to communicate with the device on Windows platform, but having trouble with **MacOSX** (tried **MacOS 10.12**).

On **Windows** I've used **HidD_SetOutputReport()**/**HidD_GetInputReport()** functions which means that the device expects the requests as **Control Transfers**. **Interrupt Transfers'** **WriteFile()**/**ReadFile()** don't seem to be able to send data where the device expects it.

**HID API** uses **IOHIDDeviceSetReport()** for the **hid_write()** function which seems to behave like **Windows**' **WriteFile()**. Also tried **libusb** but it fails when trying to **usb_claim_interface()** with **"another process has device opened for exclusive access"**. **libusb_detach_kernel_driver()** is only implemented for **linux**. I could use the **codeless kext approach** but the device is a **HID controller** it is supposed to work without a driver.

Do you know of any ways of sending a **Control Transfer on MacOS**?

Comment: Have you found an answer to this?  I've been searching for a way to do this also but so far nothing.